# Group table by field and display other fields

Tags: php, sql

I have the following sql table structure (table name 'my_table'):

```
**ID - USER_ID - FIELD_ID - VALUE**

1 - 1 - 1 - letter a

2 - 1 - 2 - letter b

3 - 1 - 3 - letter c

4 - 2 - 1 - letter a

5 - 2 - 2 - letter b
```

Then, I would like to display the results in an html table like so:

```
**USER_ID - FIELD_ID1->value - FIELD_ID2->value - FIELD_ID3->value**

1 - letter a - letter b - letter c

2 - letter a - letter b
```

Any takers??  Thanks :)

EDIT:

Here is a fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd980/5

It is the bottom table I am attempting to display results from.

Comment: You can't do like this if the number of keys is different (how do you imagine a table with different number of entries in a row?). You can do a pivot table though.

Comment: The primary key is the ID column.  I should have chosen a different name for the "key" column.  Edited.  Wouldn't it just display a blank space in the rendered html if no data is in that sql cell?

Comment: Yep, this would be 'pivot table'.

Comment: Thanks sashkello.  Any quick idea with code on getting it pulled from sql and echoed in html?  I'm researching it now.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT t.user_id,
       MAX(IF(t.field_id = 1, t.value, NULL)) AS key1,
       MAX(IF(t.field_id = 2, t.value, NULL)) AS key2,
       MAX(IF(t.field_id = 3, t.value, NULL)) AS key3
FROM my_table t
GROUP BY t.user_id
```

Comment: That worked absolutely perfectly!! You are the man!  Last question and I promise to leave you alone... how would I echo that out in an HTML table?  Something like... <td>1</td><td>Josh</td><td>35</td>  Do I need a foreach loop and variables?    EDIT:  Wait, I may have answered my own question.  Lemme fiddle for a minute :)

Comment: Here is what I'm working with:  http://pastebin.com/ugYDZwf9   But, I know it's wrong ;)  Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: And here is the first link in google by 'mysql table to html table' search: http://davidwalsh.name/html-mysql-php

Comment: Yes sir.  Thank you, thank you. Please forgive me, I am a newbie here.  How do I accept your answer, please?

Comment: even better: http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_mysql_example__display_table_as_html.xml

Comment: Got it.  Doing php/html now.  Will be back if trouble. Do you have a website with a paypal donation link?

Comment: Thank you, kindly!  I'm still struggling with outputting the results... but I'll keep hammering.  Thank you very much for getting over that hurdle I've been fighting for two days... PLUS teaching me something new :)

Comment: Bam!!  Got it. A free lesson is so seldomly seen these days!!  I volunteer on the WordPress forums, and also Volunteer on two theme forums.  Your help will go far beyond me and through others.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
Select user_id, group_concat(value,' - ') from t
Group By user_id
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e991/7)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a manual pivot:

```
select user_id,
       max(case when key = 1 then value end) as Key1,
       max(case when key = 2 then value end) as Key2,
       max(case when key = 3 then value end) as Key3
from t
group by user_id
```

This should work in any database.

Comment: Super Fast... trying it out now... one sec.

Comment: No luck.  But thank you, Gordon.  I have edited my question above, and added a link to a fiddle... if that helps at all.